# How to filter the SQL query result using regular expression or SQL functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have got below types of URLs:

```
/Fullnews/News/English/2014/2014.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2014/1221264.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2014/1221272.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2013/2013.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2013/1251272.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2012/2012.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2012/1281272.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/config.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/list.XML
```

Now I need to write SQL procedure where I will pass the "Fullnews" as parameter and my procedure will return below results

GetData("Fullnews");

```
/Fullnews/News/English/2014/1221264.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2014/1221272.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2013/1251272.XML
/Fullnews/News/English/2012/1281272.XML
```

It should filter all ther urls whose last part is not numeric (config,list etc.) and also it should not return urls whose last part is (2014,2013,2012 etc.) else (1281272, 1221264 etc.) need to rendered.

Comment: Well, show what you've got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_test
(
@parameter VARCHAR(400)
)
as
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM <tablename>
WHERE url like 
 '/'+@parameter+'/News/English/20[0-2][2-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_%.XML'
END
```

Comment: Thanks @dk, however my url can grow in future as well, so I can't hold till 7 numbers, we just need to exclude url whose last four characters are not numeric and is greater than four characters

Comment: @ManojSingh ok, changed answer to accept any characters after the 4 numeric characters with the requirement of it being at least 5 characters